# set SVG initial width and height

Tags: html, css, svg

So I wanna have this SVG inside a `col` div but I want it to be the same height of the right column. If the right col is bigger, it's all good but if it's smaller, the SVG column will win and dictate the height of others.

Is there anyway I can set an initial size of the SVG and still have it responsive in terms of height?

In short, I want the right column to dictate the height of others.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="100%">
      <line
        x1="50%" 
        y1="100%" 
        x2="50%" 
        y2="0%"
        stroke="black" 
        stroke-width="2" />

      <circle 
        cx="50%" 
        cy="10%" 
        r="5" />
  </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the desired result:

[image]

Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/napusirebu/edit?html,css,output) if you wanna play around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, seems like I just needed `height` and a `min-height` and some adjustments:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.col>svg {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <line 
        x1="50%"
        y1="100%"
        x2="50%" 
        y2="0"
        stroke="darkgray" />
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="3" />
  </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis
  </div>
</div>
```